# Why can't C++ infer array size with offset?

Tags: c++

This code fails to compile

```
template<unsigned n>
void test(char const (*)[n + 1]) { }

int main()
{
    char const arr[] = "Hi";
    test(&arr);
}
```

with error

```
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'n'
```

However, if you change `n + 1` to `n`, it compiles just fine.

Why can't the compiler deduce `n` when it has an offset added to it?

Comment: But what exactly you are trying to achieve is what I don't get? I mean the rules for compatible types require one to one match for array dimensions.

Comment: How about a mental excersize? What if the template was specified as `void test(char const (*)[(n+3)*(n-2)])`, would you expect a C++ compiler to deduce `n` as 9 when an array of 84 chars gets passed in?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: No, but that doesn't imply it couldn't handle a basic affine expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), in the " Non-deduced contexts" section:

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that
> are used to compose P do not participate in template argument
> deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either
> deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is
> used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified,
> template argument deduction fails.
>
> (...)
>
> 3. A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a
>    subexpression references a template parameter:

```
template<std::size_t N> void f(std::array<int, 2 * N> a);
std::array<int, 10> a;
f(a); // P = std::array<int, 2 * N>, A = std::array<int, 10>:
      // 2 * N is non-deduced context, N cannot be deduced
      // note: f(std::array<int, N> a) would be able to deduce N
```

> (...)
>
> In any case, if any part of a type name is non-deduced, the entire type name is non-deduced context. (...)

Because `n + 1` is a subexpresion, the whole context then cannot be deduced.

Comment: +1 thanks. But do you know if `(n)` should work then? Because it fails on Clang but works on GCC and MSVC.

Comment: @user541686 I think Clang is right. `(n)` should make `n` a subexpression, which should make the whole thing a non-deduced context. That's what Clang's error message says as well "couldn't infer template argument ..."